# how to make JOINTURE(join) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two table SALARIES and POINTAGES And between them a relationship hasMany belongsTo, I want to display for each POINTAGE a SALARIES corresponds but it gives me empty datatable.
    **consulter.blade.php**

```
@foreach($pointages as $pointage)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $pointage->datep }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->chantier }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->ouvrage }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->nbrj }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->solde }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->salarie->nom }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Pointage.php**

```
 protected $fillable = [
  'salarie_id', 'datep', 'solde', 'nbrj' , 'ouvrage' , 'chantier' , 'prime' ,
];
 public function salarie(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Salarie');
 }
```

**Salarie.php**

```
public function pointages(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Pointage');
}
```

**pointages** migration:

```
public function up(){
  Schema::table('pointages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('salarie_id')->unsigned()->after('id');
    $table->foreign('salarie_id')->references('id')->on('salaries');  
  });
}
```

**SalarieController.php**

```
 public function consulter()
     {
      $salaries = Salarie::with('pointages')->get();
      $pointages = Pointage::with(["salaries"])->has("salarie")->get();
      return view('salarie.consulter', compact('salaries','pointages'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define explicit the relationship functions:

```
// app\Salarie.php
class Salarie extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome'];
    public function pointages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pointage','salarie_id','id');
    }
}
// app\Pointage.php
class Pointage extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'salarie_id', 'datep', 'solde', 'nbrj' , 'ouvrage' , 'chantier' , 'prime' ,
      ];
    public function salarie(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Salarie');
    }
}
```

And use like below to consulter all of pointages relate with salaries table:

```
// app\Http\Controllers\SalarieController.php
class SalarieController extends Controller
{
    public function consulter()
     {
        // test your model with this simple query
        // $salaries = Salarie::find(1);
        // $pointages = $salaries->pointages()->get();
        // return view('salarie.consulter', compact('pointages'));

        // if the upon test runs well, the follow codes will work 
        $salaries_ids = Salarie::with('pointages')->pluck('id');
        $pointages  = Pointage::whereHas('salarie', function($query) use ($salaries_ids) {
            $query->whereIn('salarie_id', $salaries_ids);
        })->get();
        return view('salarie.consulter', compact('pointages'));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, ask me if you need!

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could try:

1. I'm not sure if it matters but you could try removing the brackets in de `with()` like so `Pointage::with("salaries")->has("salarie")->get();`
2. Another thing you should check if the primary and foreign keys of Salarie and Pointage are correct. [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) states the following:

   > In the example above, Eloquent will try to match the user_id from the Phone model to an id on the User model. Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id. However, if the foreign key on the Phone model is not user_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method.